# Ocultar postagens no tumblr

Tags: javascript

Eu fiz um tema pro tumblr, e o que eu queria fazer é disponibilizar 3 botões fixos na parte superior da tela: *all* (mostra todas as postagens), *text* (mostra só textos) e *images* (só imagens).

Já consegui fazer alguma coisa, mas o problema é que só funciona na primeira postagem, já que a página é em carregamento infinito. Queria ajuda para fazer isso. Vou reconstruir o que fiz e colocar o código depois, mas alguém acha que é possível?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function control(mostra) {
    if(mostra == "all"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("image").style.display="block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("text").style.display="block";
    }else if(mostra == "image"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("image").style.display="block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("text").style.display="none";
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName("image").style.display="none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("text").style.display="block";
    }
}
</script>
```

e os botões:

```
<input id="tudo" type="button" value="All" onclick=control("all") />
<input id="imagem" type="button" value="Image" onclick=control("image") />
<input id="texto" type="button" value="Text" onclick=control("text") />
```

aqui o bloco de posts:

```
<div id="posts">
{block:Posts}
    <div class="text">
        {block:Text}{block:Title}<h1>{Title}</h1>{/block:Title}{Body}{/block:Text}

        {block:Quote}
            <div id="postquote">“{Quote}”</div><br>
            {block:Source}<div id="sourcequote"> — {Source}</div>{/block:Source}
        {/block:Quote}

        {block:Link}<a href="{URL}"><h1>{Name}</h1></a>
        {block:Description}<p>{Description}</p>{/block:Description}{/block:Link}
        {block:Chat}<ul class="chat">{block:Lines}<li class="user_{UserNumber}">{block:Label}<span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label}&nbsp;{Line}</li>{/block:Lines}</ul>{/block:Chat}

        {block:Answer}
        <table width="500px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
        <td width="415px" class="question">{Question}</td>
        <td width="30px"><span class="questionarrow">◤</span></td>
        <td width="64px" class="asking"><img src="{AskerPortraitURL-64}"><br>{Asker}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="answer">{Answer}</div>
        {/block:answer}

        {block:Audio}<span class="audio"><center>{AudioPlayerBlack}</center></span>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Audio}

    </div>


        <div class="image">
            {block:Photo}<center><img src="{PhotoURL-500}"/></center>
            {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Photo}

            {block:Photoset}<center>{Photoset-500}</center>
            {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Photoset}

            {block:Video}{Video-500}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Video}
        </div>

        <div id="ssource">
            {block:ContentSource}
                <a href="{SourceURL}">{lang:Source}:{block:SourceLogo}
                <img src="{BlackLogoURL}" width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />
                {/block:SourceLogo}{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo}</a>
            {/block:ContentSource}
        </div>
</div>
    <div id="perma">
        <a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank">reblog</a>{block:HasTags}<br>{block:Tags} <a href="{TagURL}"><b>#</b>{Tag}</a>&nbsp;{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}
    </div>
{/block:Posts}
</div>
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o código atual, o endereço atual, para ver o que pode ser feito.

Comment: Oi Rodrigo, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. O que você quer saber parece possível sim. Acredito que sua pergunta esteja sendo negativada porque não dá para ajudar sem ver o seu código. O formato aqui do site é dar respostas completas que de fato resolvam o problema, e não somente dicas (sugiro uma olhada no [tour]). Para isso ser possível, a pergunta precisa ser focada. Recomendo [edit] sua pergunta e complementar com [trechos relevantes de código](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Cria uma DIV com uma *class* antes de cada bloco e faz o show/hide com JS. Em teoria deve funcionar.

Comment: muito obrigado, poisé, é que tinha parado com o porojeto quando um amigo disse desse site, então já tava com um tema diferente, to remontando pra por aqui, fazendo o que você disse funciona só nos primeiros, pois funciona com um scroll infinito... mas vou tentar, se não me engano tentei com div... tinha pensado em por div como uma variável e a cada post seria "div"+a+1, por exemplo, então ficaria, div1, div2... e usar um for i<a... acho que entendeu, mas vai funcionar só nos primeiros tambem...

Comment: acredito que o que é preciso é fazer com que quando carregue mais post, a função seja acionada, é possível?

Answer (score 1):

Muito obrigado pela ajuda, descobri o problema, eu estava pegando class, então o resultado é uma lista e o certo seria assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var imgm = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
    var txt = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
    function control(mostra) {
    if(mostra == "all"){
        for (var i=0;i<imgm.length;i+=1){
        imgm[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    for (var i=0;i<txt.length;i+=1){
        txt[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}else if(mostra == "image"){
    for (var i=0;i<imgm.length;i+=1){
        imgm[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    for (var i=0;i<txt.length;i+=1){
        txt[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}else{
    for (var i=0;i<imgm.length;i+=1){
        imgm[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    for (var i=0;i<txt.length;i+=1){
        txt[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: mesmo assim continua só as primeiras, coloquei aqui pra testar: http://exage-rado.tumblr.com/